# Angular 7 - How to avoid row swap with ng-container

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

As per the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwhpvw) tbody contains information to be displayed in two tr's. I've implemented this behavior with magical ng-container as shown below:

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
  <tr>
    <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.id}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.id}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.id}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.id}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.id}}</td>
    <td>{{hero.gender}}</td>
      </tr>
  <tr *ngIf='hero'>
    <td colspan="15" style="text-align: center">{{'Strength: '+ hero.strength}}</td>
  </tr>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

> Note: Please ignore display of duplicate columns

The issue here is at times on display of filtered records on selection of "Show even records", instead of the row with **Name, Id, Gender** displaying first; the **strength** displayed first **intermittently** at times. The filtering of records happens using Spread arrays.

I was unable to figure out the issue causing this behavior, with benefit of doubt I've added *ngIf for **2nd tr**. Could you please help assist in fixing this intermittent issue?

Appreciate your help in Advance!!

Comment: not replicable!

Comment: @Manpreet Yes, it is intermittent.. I too tried multiple ways to replicate it with that example. This doesn't happen directly during display of records, it happens only during modification of the record or filtering of records

Comment: okay, i will check while modification .. Thanks for update

Comment: @Manpreet and how are we supposed to modify the records to reproduce the error?

Comment: @BVS Have to checked your length of your heroes array? `<h2>{{heroes.length}}</h2>` That way you actually see if it an error with template or the data being passed to the template?

Comment: @Calidus, There were no template errors, in my real application even with single record I was able replicate it often on filter or update of that record. For some reason, the second tr is getting loaded in prior to first tr.

Comment: @Shravan: I've updated the stackblitz with updating of record Information, I almost tried to replicate the implementation of my real application in this example, May be due to simple data the replication of the mentioned row swapped issue is difficult. In my application it is complex DOM rendered in tbody associated with ng-container. Hope this updated example depicts what i had in my application but the complexity of DOM and manipulation with data is too high, when compared with this example, this is only 1% of what real application has.

Comment: @Manpreet: Thanks for looking into, I've updated the stackblitz with updating of record Information, I almost tried to replicate the implementation of my real application in this example, May be due to simple data the replication of the mentioned row swapped issue is difficult. In my application it is complex DOM rendered in tbody associated with ng-container. Hope this updated example depicts what i had in my application but the complexity of DOM and manipulation with data is too high, when compared with this example, this is only 1% of what real application has.